# Wordpress: Adding multiple category-names & tag-names from page to <body>

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Please refer to code below.

I have already a code who gives *category-names* and *tag-names* to the `<body>`. But it only puts in one *category* and one *tag*, not all. What do i have to update in my code to tell wordpress that it should get all *tags* and *categories* and put that as 'class' into the `<body>`?

---

```
// category-name to body

function add_category_name($classes = '') {
if( is_page() )
    {
      $category = get_the_category();
      $classes[] = 'category-'.$category[0]->slug;
    }
   return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class','add_category_name');


// tag-name in body

function add_tag_name($classes = '') {
if( is_page() )
    {
     $tag = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
     $classes[] = 'tag-'.$tag[0]->slug;
    }
   return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class','add_tag_name');
```

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You can add this code to your custom functions.php file:

```
// add tags and categories to pages

function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_and_tag_archives' );
}

function category_and_tag_archives( $wp_query ) {
$my_post_array = array('post','page');

    if ( $wp_query->get( 'category_name' ) || $wp_query->get( 'cat' ) )
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $my_post_array );

    if ( $wp_query->get( 'tag' ) )
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $my_post_array );

}

// add tags and categorys as class to <body>

function add_categories_and_tags( $classes = '' ) {
    if( is_page() ) {
        $categories = get_the_category();
        foreach( $categories as $category ) {
            $classes[] = 'category-'.$category->slug;
        }
        $tags = get_the_tags();
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
            $classes[] = 'tag-'.$tag->slug;
        }
    }
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_categories_and_tags' );
```

Works perfect, tested in WordPress 4.8